# XSS filtering on input->post() while form validator is active in Ci

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss

I was wondering. I'm using the form validation class in codeigniter. On most of my input fields I have xss filtering turned on:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required|xss_clean');
```

My question. The input class itself also has an XSS filtering parameter. Is it necessary to set this parameter as well, even when its gone trough the validator?

Comment: No need to use twice the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The Input class has the ability to filter input automatically to prevent cross-site scripting attacks.

**If you want the filter to run automatically every time it encounters POST or COOKIE data you can enable it by opening your `application/config/config.php` file and setting this**:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

OR

```
$this->input->post('some_data', TRUE); // Specific item
$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);        // All POST items
```

And you no need use prepping functions (xss_clean)